# Retrieve music info from .aac streaming in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm trying to make a simple radio player which should stream a public domain online radio in pure JavaScript. I found one [here](http://publicdomainradio.org/).
I've added a simple `<audio>` player which have the url retrieved from the site as `src`. It is an `.aac` file. I've read that some streaming channels send informations about the author, the song and more through the audio chunks while streaming, so I think that these information can be periodically retrieved in the `timeupdate` event of the audio control, however I have no idea if this is true and how it could be done, as I searched the internet without finding anything. I have this simple code:

```
<audio id="audPlr">
    <source src="http://relay.publicdomainradio.org:80/jazz_swing.aac">
</audio>

<script>
    var msc = document.getElementById("audPlr");
    msc.play();
</script>
```

It works, but I need to display those informations.

EDIT:

I managed to make a very simple player with metadata thanks to Brad's help and [Icecast Metadata JS](https://github.com/eshaz/icecast-metadata-js), the code is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head></head>

  <script src="icecast-metadata-player/icecast-metadata-player-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    const onMetadata = (metadata) => {
        document.getElementById("metadata").innerHTML = 
metadata.StreamTitle;
      };
      const player = 
        new IcecastMetadataPlayer(
          "https://ice2.somafm.com/dronezone-128-mp3",
          { onMetadata }
        );
  </script>

  <body>
    <button onclick="player.play();"> Play </button>
    <button onclick="player.stop();"> Stop </button>
    <p> Now Playing: <span id="metadata"></span> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i try to get metadata from https://ice2.somafm.com/dronezone-128-mp3, it works perfectly, but when I try from, for example, https://deeperlink.com:8082/stream I got `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error.
I think I need to set the custom header in the `IcecastMetadataPlayer` request, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I've also read about the [Web Audio API](https://web.dev/webaudio-intro/), maybe I could use this to retrieve information from decoded data?

Answer (score 1):

> I've added a simple  player which have the url retrieved from the site as src. It is an .aac file.

It isn't a file.  This is just a URL convention being used.  What you have is actually a Icecast server sending you AAC audio within an ADTS stream.  Metadata is sent at a regular interval, if requested.  Add this header to your request data:

```
Icy-MetaData: 1
```

Then in the response headers, you'll see something like:

```
Icy-MetaInt: 8192
```

That means, every 8,192 bytes there will be a metadata block.

The easiest way to implement this sort of player on the web is to use MediaSource Extensions.

Check out Ethan's repo here, for an implementation example:  https://github.com/eshaz/icecast-metadata-js

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to implement info display in vanilla Javascript, but as I can see the library that you linked is made with React. I've never used it, so if possible I'd rather avoid any external library/environment.

Comment: @user2959923 Yeah, you can still use it an example though as to how to make your own project.

Answer (score 0):

> I got No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource error.

It looks like from their header they're sending it now, does it still not work?

```
Server: mscp-web
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2022 00:20:16 GMT
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: *
X-Robots-Tag: none
X-Powered-By: MSCP Pro+ (https://mscp.pro)
icy-br: 192
ice-audio-info: bitrate=192;channels=2;samplerate=44100
icy-description: Playing relaxing ambiental nature music with piano and guitar
icy-genre: Relaxation
icy-name: Deep Relax
icy-pub: 0
icy-url: https://www.deeplink.stream
```

The only other thing I can think of is that it appears to not be coming off an Icecast server, but rather a proxy as part of MSCP https://mscp.pro

Comment: Yes, still the same error. Sorry for the late reply